# Node Sass not supporting current environment despite rebuilds and uninstalls with version 4.12 on OS X 64-bit

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, version-control, node-sass

I'm using the latest version of Node(12.8) with the Node-Sass package (4.12.0). Full documentation on the version here: (https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases). However, using any command results in the infamous message I've seen with other users...only none of the suggestions I've researched help. The issue:

```
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (72)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.7.2
```

So here's where I'm stumped. I've used as many solutions I've been able to find:

- This won't work:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/sass/node-sass.git
cd node-sass
npm install
node scripts/build -f
```

or this alone:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

- Nor does deleting node_modules, and reinstalling via npm install
- Switched around to older versions of Node and Node-Sass
- And here are my current versions:

```
npm -v 6.10.2
node -v v12.8.0
-p process.version:
{
  node: '12.8.0',
  v8: '7.5.288.22-node.16',
  uv: '1.30.1',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  modules: '72',
  nghttp2: '1.39.1',
  napi: '4',
  llhttp: '1.1.4',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  openssl: '1.1.1c',
  cldr: '35.1',
  icu: '64.2',
  tz: '2019a',
  unicode: '12.1'
}
```

And the package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "nan": "^2.14.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0"
  }
```

Ultimately I just want to use

```
node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w
```

for watching changes/compiling later.

Thank you in advance! I've been confused about this for hours :/

Answer (score 0):

> For more information on which environments are supported please see:
>   https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.7.2

You might have the direct 4.12.0 dependency in your package.json, but one of your other dependencies is trying to install 4.7.2, which isn't compatible with Node 12